# Include an external config folder when using Maven to create a WAR

Tags: maven

I have config folder in project base directory. When I am trying to build the war the folder is not getting added in war file. I have external jar which uses this folder to read the log4j.properties.

Inisde Jar code: ("config/log4j.properties")

When I am trying to access the application in tomcat server I am getting config/log4j.properties path not found.

Current Folder Structure

Project
  --src/main/
  --src/test
  --src/resource
  --lib
  --config(inside config log4j.properties)
   --target

Inside lib folder i have some custom jar that i am adding inside my war file with maven plugin.
That custom jar reading config folder for log4j properties.this is springboot app.when i am trying to run the app through eclipse its working file.But when i am trying to build a war and manually deploying war on tomcat then its failing.I am not sure where should i keep this config folder inside war so that custom jar can read it.

Comment: Any help. I am struggling with this since 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Maven tends to work *well* when you adopt its conventions but when you do not then you might find things stop working. 
So, my advice is to structure your project according to the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Given this project structure:

```
src
 |   |-- main
 |   |   |-- resources
 |   |   |   |-- config
 |   |   |   |   | -- log4j.properties
```

The Maven WAR plugin will, by default, create a WAR with this content:

```
WEB-INF
 |   |-- ...
 |   |
 |   |-- config
 |   |       -- log4j.properties
```

So, anything which attempts to load config/log4j.properties from the classpath will find that log4j.properties file

If you really cannot cannot move the `config` folder to `src/main/resources` then you can use the Maven WAR plugin to [add an external resource](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html), for example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>config</directory>
          <targetPath>WEB-INF/config</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This will result in `log4j.properties` being copied into `WEB-INF/config` within your WAR i.e. the same end result as if you would get if you moved `config` from the root of your project to `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Its not Wokring.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some specifics? Maybe explain what you tried, what happened and what - exactly - you mean by "not Wokring"? If you do reply, please update the original question, since it's much easier to read questions than comments.

Comment: I can't follow the project struicture you show in your question. Could you show it as a tree view so that it's clear which directories belong where. It seems like you have folders named `lib` and `config` in the project root and that you also have a folder named `resources` within the `src` folder. None of these conform to Maven standards. I've updated my answer to try to show a project structure which will _just work_ for you.